# how can a movable Rpi(B) can follow another movable Rpi(A)

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have 2 computer named A and B. Both can move. Both can be connected in peer-to-peer network using wifi. Additional sensor and camera can also be added in one computer which is raspberry pi (computer B). I want to add some formation driving functionality so that computer B always try to follow computer A. if computer A starts moving away, computer B also follows A in same direction. I don’t want to maintain some constant distance between them. Computer B’s objective is to reach computer A. there can be another moving computer C but B should only follow A not C.

I could have used GPS if I want to test it outside in big ground, however in indoors I think GPS approach wont work.

Any feasible ideas which can be implemented without much complexity.

thanks

agoswami

Comment: Can you add anything to A - like a beacon, either IR, RF, or ultrasonic, or even just a coloured sticker or barcode or something? Things like GPS can't manage very good accuracy relative to the size of your devices. Something that can be easily homed-in on, such as a flashing IR LED, would be my choice. Machine vision is hard & CPU-intensive, tracking a point like an LED or reflector is much easier with "dumb" sensors.

Answer (score 1):

If GPS is not an option I would try to go to a Gyroscope/accelerometer. 
(check it [here](http://marks-space.com/2013/04/29/guide-to-interfacing-a-gyro-and-accelerometer-with-a-raspberry-pi/) , rasp pi guide to accelerometer/gyro)

- On start node A and node B exchange locations. (both at X= 0 Y =0 regardess of their poition)
- Node A on detecting acceleration sends direction and speed to node B
- Node B keeps node A location, on locationA change event node B moves in it´s direction

The other option: maybe checking wifi signal strengh?
But nodeB would have to move in several directions before getting improved signal strength.

Comment: This seems to assume they both start next to each other, which wasn't stated as being the case?

Comment: No problem at all, nodeB just need to have the CurrentCoordenates and the PreviousIterationCoordenates in order to determine direction/speed. It´s assumed that both nodes start in wifi-range distance of each other.